# How to install SharePoint 2016 with AppFabric Problems

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows, app-fabric

I have downloaded and installed all of the prerequisite installation files for SharePoint 2016. I even installed AppFabric. Afterwards, when attempting to install SharePoint, I receive the following errors:

This product requires Windows Server AppFabric with all its features and re-run setup.
Windows Server AppFabric is not correctly configured. You should uninstall Windows Server AppFabric and reinstall it using the SharePoint Product Preparation tool.
It gets better:

I uninstalled AppFabric with an uninstall tool. However, it is still displayed in my Windows applications.
I ran SharePoint's prerequisiteinstaller.exe and placed the WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64 exe along with AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU exe in the prerequisiteinstallerfiles folder to no avail. The program eventually stops running during the execution of setup.
Can anyone provide a suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

To install `WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe`, try to do the following:

- Move `WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe` to drive `C:/`
- Type the following command line in PowerShell

  ```
    .\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe /i CacheClient,CachingService,CacheAdmin /gac
  ```
- Wait until AppFabric installation finish.
- Click on `‘AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe’` to install the AppFabric patch.
- Reboot the server > Run SharePoint Installation again where the message error should not be listed again.

> For more details check **[Windows Server AppFabric is not correctly configured. You Should uninstall Windows Server AppFabric and reinstall it using The SharePoint Products Preparation Tool.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured-as-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites/)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69070/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-how-to-install-sharepoint-2016-with-appfabric-p).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is IE being set to not download files and also IE enhanced security being on, so turn it off[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "install from network share" microsoft solution by installing AppFabric with the prerequisites installer with command line specifying the installer path:

```
PrerequisiteInstaller.exe /AppFabric:"<path to installers>\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe"
```

Ref: [Install the SharePoint Server prerequisites at the command prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ie/SharePoint/install/install-prerequisites-from-network-share#install-the-sharepoint-server-prerequisites-at-the-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had not noticed PrerequisiteInstaller.exe and started from setup.exe. It showed requirements which I've downloaded and installed manually. I've even installed and configured appfabric 1.1 manually, but SP 2019 failed to install complaining on wrong appfabric installation/configuration.

In my case after removing appfabric I could not install it again by neither manual installation or installation through PrerequisiteInstaller.

To resolve the issue, I've:

1. Reinstalled windows server (2016 in my case)
2. Run PrerequisiteInstaller.exe first (all components have been installed)
3. Run setup.exe (sp2019 has been installed)